# writing unit test (RSpec) with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nokogiri, rspec2

In my current application I have a module to read (extract) HTML from an external website. For an example say I'm extracting the following div

```
<div class='sample'>
  <p class="name">Jhon Smith</p>
  <div class="address">
    No30, 5th Street,
    Home Town 
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have methods to read

- 1 - name
- 2 - address

Ex : `def name(htmlDiv) -> return "Jhon Smith"`

```
def address(htmlDiv) -> return " No30, 5th Street,Home Town "
```

My question is how can I unit test these methods using rspec ? my thinking is to do as follows

- have a string of the above html inside spec/factories directory
- have a spec file with above methods inside spec/lib/*_spec.rb
- read the string and pass to the div as the parameter

  1. So is this approach is correct ?
  2. is there any other easy/ methodical way of doing testing when there
     in html page reading involved?

I'm on

- Rails3
- Rapec 2.0
- nokogiri
- restclient

Answer (score 0):

When unit-testing I would "stub" this HTML:

```
describe MyExtractor do
 let(:raw_html) { "<div>...</div>" }
 let(:name) { 'John' }
 let(:address) { 'Something' }

 subject { described_class.new(raw_html) }

 its(:name) { should eq name }
 its(:address) { should eq address }
end
```

You can extract specific `context`s from this (when HTML is malformed, when is blank, when there is no address, etc.) to test edge cases (you can later on extract a shared example for this).

Later on you can do an integration test when you will provide this HTML to be parsed from "real" source (probably stubbed again with webmock or something).

Comment: May be its better to save the source of a page and read it from a file.